# After read my pubspec.yaml file, is my app using encryption?

Tags: flutter, encryption

I'm close to publish my first app on the App Store and they asked me if I'm using encryption.
After reading something on the internet I can say that I'm not writing explicit code to encrypt data on the web, all the internet requests made are on Google Cloud Firebase service like : Firestore, Firebase Storage and Auth.
Geolocator and geocoding are in the pubspec but I'm not using them so I could delete.
This is the `pubspec.yaml` file :

```
firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
google_sign_in: ^5.0.1
font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
google_fonts: ^2.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.0.0
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
provider: ^5.0.0
bottom_navy_bar: ^6.0.0
firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
geolocator: ^7.0.1
geocoding: ^2.0.0
location_permissions: ^3.0.0+1
path_provider: ^2.0.1
image_picker: ^0.7.4
firebase_image: ^1.0.1
```

What do you think?

Comment: would highly recommend getting legal advice, i want to clarify im not a lawyer and therefore everything i say here on out is to be taken as speculation. 
my opinion: even a simple api request over https would technically qualify a yes for the question, as it uses encryption and therefore technically needs to be declared as outlined in the corresponding [article from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations). same reasoning could be applied to firestore/database requests.

Comment: Ok thank you...Well Google should be have wrote somewhere if their API uses encryption on not, right?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Firebase for all your authentication / database / storage, etc. you have outsourced anything that would need encryption to Google.

You haven't imported an http library which leads me to believe you're not making any unencrypted web service calls.

Your app is fine. They're really looking for people sending unencrypted credentials or other sensitive data through http to insecure servers. Big red flag type stuff.

If you would be afraid to put your own data into your app, don't publish it. Otherwise, it's likely just fine.

I am not a lawyer nor is this legal advice.

Comment: Ok so for encryption they mean if I'm doing secure calls on the web (with https for example) or if I'm sending data in an insecure way?

Comment: Once again this is just my opinion but I would say you are correct.

Comment: I understand it's just an opinion, we're talking...I was looking at [Firebase Security and Privacy](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy) seems they use encryption I need just some more informations

Comment: They do use encryption. I wouldn't think any harder about it. You're using Firebase (Google) services for all your data.